# How to assemble preemptive auth in curl command , while using POST method

Tags: rest, curl, soapui

I need to use POST method for a REST API.It's working perfectly in SOAP UI while i select "Preemptive Authentication" , I need to assemble this authentication option in Curl.

At Web service , preemptive properties has not set. It has only Basic authentication system with username & password.

I have tried --anyauth , it's not working. I have below command.

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" --verbose -u username:password http://example.net:1234/api/Flows/UpdateStatus -d '{"EventId": "123","Status": "success"}'
```

I am always getting below error.

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Comment: "Preemptive Authentication" is not a common HTTP term. Does this even return a 401 response? If so, what headers does the response contain? (and please don't use `-X  POST` when you already use `-d` which implies POST!)

Comment: Thank You Daniel ,There are no header , it has only basic authentication with user & password. I have tried with providing base64 encoded value of user & password at header section , it got worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried with providing base64 encoded value of user & password at header section instead of providing user & password under user section ,and it got worked for me.

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" --verbose -H "Authorization: Basic Base64_encoded_value_of_user_&_password" http://example.net:1234/api/Flows/UpdateStatus -d '{"EventId": "123","Status": "success"}'
```